# Strange error when $().html json data

Tags: jquery, json, utf-8

It seems that when I want to show JSON data if it has a ' in it the jquery adds \'

for e.g. it\'s

I am wondering what it the best way to correct this?

Comment: Please post your code and we can all have a look to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this please

```
JSON.stringify(data1)
```